# Hangfire: search for a job that ran at a specific time

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, hangfire

I'm working with a .net application that use Hangfire 1.7.28.

A critical bug that occurred, I know the exact time when it happened and I think that it was caused by a scheduled job.

For this reason I need to understand exactly witch **Job** was **running** in that **exact moment**.

I see that in the dashboard the duration and the succeeded time for last 24 hours but in a format not really easy to filter by.
I tried also to see the underlaying data from the database but I wasn't able to detect the fable that holds those informations.

Is it possible to see the job that ran at a certain datetime?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try someting like this:

```
var targetTime = new DateTime(2023, 3, 31, 12, 0, 0); 
var monitoringApi = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

// get succeeded jobs in the minute that contains the target datetime
var jobs = monitoringApi.SucceededJobs(targetTime, targetTime.AddMinutes(1), 0, int.MaxValue); 

foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Job ID: {job.Key}, Type: {job.Value.Job.Type}, Method: {job.Value.Job.Method.Name}, Result: {job.Value.Result}");
}
```

Comment: Wold it be possible to consume the API in your example from Postman or curl or?

Comment: Is `SucceededJobs` an extension method? I don't see `SucceededJobs()` accepting this many arguments in `IMonitoringApi` definition. [Hangfire GitHub](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Storage/IMonitoringApi.cs).